# When transferring text from a cell to a label in the next VC, it doesn't appear the first time the VC is opened

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making an app where you create memories into a tableView and you tap on a cell and it takes you to its designated VC, I am trying to make it so that when the cell is tapped, the text from inside that table cell is taken into the label in the next VC. This works but the problem is that when the view is first opened, the text doesn't appear inside the label, even though the console says that the text has loaded correctly:

[TableView with a test cell in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxrhi.png)

[First time the VC for the cell is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z3uJ.png)

[Console saying that the text has transferred and loaded correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz8GG.png)

[Second time the VC is opened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMOqt.png)

Here is my transferring and loading code for the ViewControllers:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

var selectedRow : Int = 0 + 1 

var selectedNameVC : String?

var favourites: [NSManagedObject] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

              //MARK:- New CoreData methods
        let favMemory = favourites[indexPath.row]
              cell.textLabel?.text = favMemory.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
              return cell
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        selectedRow = indexPath.row


        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        let favMemory = cell?.textLabel?.text
        selectedNameVC = favMemory
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? FavouritesViewController {
            destination.row = selectedRow
            destination.selectedName = selectedNameVC


        }
    }
```

```
class FavouritesViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

var selectedName: String?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        labelText.text = selectedName

        if labelText.text == "" as String? {
            print("Title has not loaded correctly.")
        } else {
            print("Title has loaded correctly.")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't get values from cells... get them from your data source (which is what you used to ***set*** the values).

So, in `didSelectRowAt` instead of:

```
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    let favMemory = cell?.textLabel?.text
```

you should do:

```
    let favMemory = favourites[indexPath.row]
```

However, that's not what's causing your issue.

I'm assuming in your Storyboard you have a "Show Segue" connected from your prototype cell to your `FavouritesViewController`. If that's the case, `prepare(for segue: ...)` is called ***before*** `didSelectRowAt`. To confirm this, change your code to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    selectedRow = indexPath.row

    // don't do this        
    //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    //let favMemory = cell?.textLabel?.text

    let favMemory = favourites[indexPath.row]

    print("In didSelectRowAt --- Setting var selectedNameVC = favMemory: \(favMemory)")

    selectedNameVC = favMemory

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? FavouritesViewController {

        print("In prepareForSegue --- Setting selectedName in FavouritesViewController = selectedNameVC: \(selectedNameVC)")

        destination.row = selectedRow
        destination.selectedName = selectedNameVC
    }

}
```

This is what you should see in the debug console:

```
In prepareForSegue --- Setting selectedName in FavouritesViewController = selectedNameVC: nil
In didSelectRowAt --- Setting var selectedNameVC = favMemory: Test
Title has loaded correctly.
```

As you see, `prepareForSegue` runs first, so the value of `selectedNameVC` is `nil` (it hasn't been set yet).

To fix this, you could set your variables in `willSelectRowAt` ***instead of*** in `didSelectRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    let favMemory = favourites[indexPath.row]
    selectedNameVC = favMemory

    return indexPath

}
```

Alternatively, create your Segue in Storyboard, but do *not* connect it to the cell. Instead, give it an Identifier (such as "ShowFavourites"), and in `didSelectRowAt`, set your vars and call `performSegue`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    let favMemory = favourites[indexPath.row]
    selectedNameVC = favMemory
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowFavourites", sender: nil)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like an absolute charm!